# How to pass dynamically generated div id to ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey i've got some problem.

My website is divided into two columns. On the left is sidebar which contains list of users dynamically generated from database, on the right-hand side should be unique chart generated by javascript framework (ajax) based on user_id. And this chart should be shown after choosing some user from list. The php file live-data.php which is used by this javascript/ajax needs GET parameter. Now it's:

> url: "php/live-data.php"

and

> $.get("php/live-data.php?Consultar=1", function(UltimosDatos)

but it should be

> url: "php/live-data.php?user_id=2"

and

> $.get("php/live-data.php?user_id=2&Consultar=1", function(UltimosDatos)

Where 2 is user_id got after clicking some user name from dynamically generated list. The php script live-data.php is ready for GET variable and returns proper json for chart framwork (this javascript shown below). I dont know how to pass div id to this ajax code.

**HTML+PHP:**

```
<div id="left" class="pre-scrollable col-lg-3">
    <div class="list-group">
        <?php include("php/dbSettings.php");
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id");
        if (!$result) {
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<a href="#'.$user['user_id'].'" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">' . $user['firstName'] . " " .$user['lastName'] . '</a>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right" class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php include( "php/dbSettings.php"); 
        $result=$ conn->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id"); 
        if (!$result) { 
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
        } 
        while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="'.$user['user_id'].'">
        <div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>';
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Ajax:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var ultimox;
            var ultimoy;

            $.ajax({
                url: "php/live-data.php", //i want this line to be "php/live-data.php?user_id=2" and 2 is variable got from user list onlick
                type: 'get',
                success: function(DatosRecuperados) {
                    $.each(DatosRecuperados, function(i, o) {
                        //some deleted code - unimportant
                    });

                    //some deleted code - unimportant

                    $('#chart').highcharts({
                        //draws chart
                    });

                }
            });
        });
        setInterval(function() {
                $.get("php/live-data.php?Consultar=1", function(UltimosDatos) { //i want this line to be "php/live-data.php?php/live-data.php?Consultar=1&user_id=2" and 2 is variable got from user list onlick
                        //updates chart
                    }
                });
        }, 1000);

        //some deleted code - unimportant

    });
</script>
```

I hope someone can help me on my way.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the hash will be set to the user id when the anchor is clicked, based on this `<a href="#'.$user['user_id'].'"` so you could read the hash value and pass it as data on the request. Either this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "php/live-data.php?user_id=" + window.location.hash.substr(1), 
  type: 'get',
  success: function(DatosRecuperados) {
    // ...

  }
});
```

or this:

```js
var dataObj = {};
dataObj['user_id'] = window.location.hash.substr(1); //create a data object to pass on query string, set user id value

$.ajax({
  url: "php/live-data.php", 
  type: 'get',
  data: dataObj, //pass object with request
  success: function(DatosRecuperados) {
    // ...

  }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me a little bit more? Im a beginner. I've updated my code adding your solution but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Did you do the same method for the second ajax request? something like `$.get("php/live-data.php?Consultar=1&user_data=" + window.location.hash.substr(1), function(UltimosDatos)` ?

Comment: Yes. Here is a full index.php code http://wklej.org/id/2450433/ . The right hand side of website is not refreshing. Nothing happens when i click on link from user list.

Comment: The way you have it set up now, it updates each second, did you wait the full second after you clicked for it to refresh?

Comment: Yeah. It must be something wrong with passing this variable to ajax. Then i put constant value like this php/live-data.php?driver_id=2 everything works fine i mean chart is static but its shown, but when i use your way nothing comes up to the screen. Its difficult problem.